# Как сделать, чтобы код js выполнялся асинхронно в yii2

Tags: yii2

Как сделать, чтобы код js выполнялся асинхронно в yii2?

```
<?php $this->registerJs('

                if(' . $count_files .' > 2){

                    var step_unzip = ' . $step_unzip .';
                    var actual_procent = 0;
                    for(var i = 2; i < ' . $count_files .'; i++){

                        $.ajax({
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: \'/update/unrar\',
                            success: function(data) {

                                //alert(step_unzip); 

                               actual_procent = actual_procent + step_unzip;
                               $("#w0 .progress-bar-success.progress-bar").attr("style","width:" + actual_procent + "%");
                            }
                        });     

                    }

                    document.getElementById("unzip").innerHTML = "Файлы Разархивированы!<span class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></span>";

                    setTimeout((function() { $("#w0 .progress-bar-success.progress-bar").attr("style","width:1%"); }), 1000);


                }else{
                    alert("Вы не положили zip архивы из росреестра!");
                    $(".body-content").remove();
                }
            ');

?>
```

Comment: `await  $.ajax({...` запускать асинхронно.  Только с таким подходом вставки js в html без бабеля будет проблема браузерной поддержки.

Comment: Не работает Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: да, нужно еще завернуть весь js в самозапускающуюся async функцию `(async () => { ... })();`